# Udacity Murder Mystery - javascript not saving variable

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow and my first problem where I've hit a wall.

```js
    var room = "ballroom";
    var suspect = "Mr. Kalehoff";
    
    var weapon = "";
    var solved = true;
    
    if (room === "dining room" && suspect === "Mr. Parkes") {
        weapon === "knife";
        solved === true;
    } else if (room === "gallery") {
        weapon === "trophy";
        solved === true;
    } else if (room === "ballroom" && suspect === "Mr. Kalehoff") {
        weapon === "pool stick";
        solved === true;
    } else {
        weapon === "poison";
        solved === false;
    }
    
    if (solved) {
     console.log(suspect + " did it in the " + room + " with the " + weapon + "!");
    }
```

In the javascript code above the value of variable **weapon** and **solved** won't save and reflect on the console even though I've changed **room** and **suspect** to meet the condition; the statement won't work.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated. 
Hopefully it all makes sense.
Cheers!

Comment: Can you post a snippet?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt OP did.

Comment: Thats a code.. I'm asking for snippet

Comment: Use `=` to assign a variable. Only use `===` when you're trying to *compare*.

Comment: So what exactly `solved === true;` supposed to be? you're not saving anything to the variable `solved` (Same goes for `weapon === <xxxx>`)

Comment: Got it now, thanks everyone!

Comment: @Teemaister Please consider accepting one of the answers to your question if you find it helpful (Click on the green "V" icon)

Comment: It's because u r using comparision(===) instead of assign(=) weapon === "pool stick"; will just compare "" and "pool stick" and return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the if & else you need to assign the value using single `=`

```js
var room = "ballroom";
var suspect = "Mr. Kalehoff";

var weapon = "";
var solved = true;

if (room === "dining room" && suspect === "Mr. Parkes") {
  weapon = "knife"; //changed here
  solved = true;    //changed here
} else if (room === "gallery") {
  weapon = "trophy";   //changed here
  solved = true;       //changed here
} else if (room === "ballroom" && suspect === "Mr. Kalehoff") {
  weapon = "pool stick";   //changed here
  solved = true;           //changed here
} else {
  weapon = "poison";       //changed here
  solved = false;          //changed here
}

if (solved) {
  console.log(suspect + " did it in the " + room + " with the " + weapon + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For assignment operation (or save ) value to a variable you have to use single = symbol. 
For more reference on assignment operation

 [1.w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp)

[2.developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

So use

```
weapon = "knife";
solved = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

the variables "weapon" and "solved" in the else if statements need use only 1 '='.
like this:

```
weapon = "knife";
solved = true;
```

Using just 1 '=' sets the variable (weapon) with the new value (knife).
Using 3 '===' is asking does this equal the value and type of that. in other words, what you were doing was asking if "weapon" matches "knife", which would output 'false'. === means specifically matching the TYPE and VALUE, not just value. whereas == would just compare the value, so "1" == 1 would output 'true' because javascript is only comparing the value, even though one is a string and one is a number. but === compares value AND type, so "1" === 1 would output 'false' because even though the values are the same, the types are different (one is a string and one is a number)

Refer to Udacity/Grow With Google lesson 11.19 - Equality.